# TypeError: pchstr must be a non-empty string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, hash

Code for argon2:

```
const usercheck = userModel.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
})

const pwcheck = userModel.findOne({
    password: mongoose.Query
})

if(!usercheck) return res.status(400).json({success: false, message: "Username not found."})
try {
    if (await argon2.verify(pwcheck, req.body.password)) {
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, message:"Logged in!" })
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'invaild password' })
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
```

How do I get the string from the mongoose database? and then so I can give it to argon2 to verify it

Comment: Did you forget to use `await` keyword ? when you read data from `userModel.findOne()`

Comment: nope, as u said right now i used await and it fixes some issues but still same thing

Comment: TypeError: pchstr must be a non-empty string
    at deserialize (C:\Users\User\Desktop\starrain-backend\node_modules\@phc\format\index.js:143:11)
    at Object.verify (C:\Users\Nerox\Desktop\starrain-backend\node_modules\argon2\argon2.js:55:73)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\starrain-backend\index.js:112:26
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)

Comment: @neroxreal What is pchstr? It isn't visible in the code you have provided above.

Comment: im not sure what is that.

Comment: Check if this helps - https://github.com/JSCasts-episodes/ep17-admin-bro-startup-part2/issues/1

Answer (score 3):

The query saved to the `pwcheck` variable is an object.
Argon needs a **hash value** to compare the plain text with. The first argument should be a hash and the second argument the plain text to be compared.